# Calling 1 flow from 2 flow triggers at the same time

Tags: flow, process-builder

Is it possible to trigger the same flow from 2 different flow triggers (process builder) at the same time? Both pass it the same variables but with different values.

I'm wondering if I should create 2 flows, one for each flow trigger instead.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

When you create two processes triggering on, let's say, a Case update, invoking the same Flow, two instances of that flow will trigger and run seperately.

They cannot however depend on each onther's flows, because the firing sequence might be random.